Separate API's with the same secret key have incompatible JWT's
I have 2 different api's with login endpoints, one using Laravel's Tymon library and the other one is a custom api I made with golang, both are using the exact same secret key and originally (since I've never worked with JWT's before) I assumed that just having the same secret key would be enough to make them interchangeable (plan is to be able to use the jwt generated by Laravel for example to access the custom api's protected endpoints with it) however, the jwt's generated by Laravel always gave me an error with my custom api, keep in mind the headers are the exact same and I went and adjusted the payload for the ones generated by the api so that it's basically the same as the Laravel one, and yet if I try to use the Laravel ones it still fails, any idea why is this happening?
{
  "alg": "HS256",
  "typ": "JWT"
}

Edit: the error that I get specifically is :    "error": "Token validation error"
Edit 2 : Example of payload for both jwts
Example 1: (Laravel jwt)
{
  "iss": "http://laravel-project.local/login",
  "iat": 1719428375,
  "exp": 1719431975,
  "nbf": 1719428375,
  "jti": "2YDruiJm1dwGJspd",
  "sub": "1",
  "prv": "23bd5c8949f600adb39e701c400872db7a5976f7"
}

Example 2 (api generated payload)

{
  "exp": 1719515666,
  "iat": 1719429266,
  "iss": "http://localhost:8000/login",
  "nbf": 1719429266,
  "jti": "i8k2MrveuE4BFg2J",
  "sub": "1",
  "prv": "23bd5c8949f600adb39e701c400872db7a5976f7"
}

Trying to generate jwt with exact same private key, but jwt is failing on seperate apis.

"jwt's generated by Laravel always gave me an error" Which one?

Sorry for the confusion, I meant that when I try to use a jwt generated by the tymon library with a protected route of my other api, I would get an error that the token was invalid.

Maybe the payload generated by Tymon is not the one expected by the Go API?

I modified them so that the payloads are nearly identical
Example 1: (Laravel jwt)
{
"iss": "http://laravel-project.local/login",
"iat": 1719428375,
"exp": 1719431975,
"nbf": 1719428375,
"jti": "2YDruiJm1dwGJspd",
"sub": "1",
"prv": "23bd5c8949f600adb39e701c400872db7a5976f7"
}
Example 2 (api generated payload)
{
"exp": 1719515666,
"iat": 1719429266,
"iss": "http://localhost:8000/login",
"nbf": 1719429266,
"jti": "i8k2MrveuE4BFg2J",
"sub": "1",
"prv": "23bd5c8949f600adb39e701c400872db7a5976f7"
}

This would be easier to answer with a reproducible example (i.e. key and JWT as const and code showing an attempt to decode token). Currently we don't even know which JWT library you are using. One thing I did note is that the Laravel JWT is only valid for one hour (whereas the API one is valid for a day); did you consider the validity periods when testing?
